# Create symlink with pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

I want to test if Python code is working with symlinks properly. How can I create symlinks (e.g. equivalent to how [`os.symlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.symlink) can be used) in a faked filesystem based on [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) in a Python2/3 compatible way?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For Python 3.x, the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) package is in the standard library. For Python 2.7 you can use the backport [`pathlib2`](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/).

Both packages have a [`.symlink_to(target, target_is_directory=False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.symlink_to) method which should do what you want.

From experience, Python 2 does not like to make symbolic links in Windows environments, but Python 3 supports NTFS symbolic links. Linux is happy making symlinks too. Other environments I can't speak for.

Here is an example usage

```
In [1]: from pathlib import Path                                                                                                                                                                              

In [2]: Path('textfile.txt').write_text('hello world!')                                                                                                                                                       
Out[2]: 12

In [3]: print(list(Path('.').rglob('*.*')))                                                                                                                                                                   
[PosixPath('textfile.txt')]

In [4]: Path('link-to-textfile.txt').symlink_to(Path('textfile.txt'))                                                                                                                                         

In [5]: print(list(Path('.').rglob('*.*')))                                                                                                                                                                  
[PosixPath('textfile.txt'), PosixPath('link-to-textfile.txt')]

In [6]: Path('link-to-textfile.txt').read_text()                                                                                                                                                             
Out[6]: 'hello world!'
```

Comment: As a side note, both packages also have a [`.is_symlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_symlink) method that may be useful to you.

Comment: I created a symlink to a file with `Path.symlink_to()`. For debugging I am using [`Path.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) to print dirs and files. However I am not seeing the target but the Path only. Is there a way to print targets?

Comment: I added an example to the original answer. The usage is generally `Path('the-link-you-want-to-create').symlink_to('the-original-file')`. You can check if a given `Path('file')` exists with the `.resolve()`, `.exists()`, or `.is_symlink()` methods (depending on what you're checking).

Comment: I am just fine with your answer. It turned out my problem is not the test, but the production code. The production code has to find files and symlinked files, has to be compatible with Python2.6 up to Python3.X and that it may not depend on any functionality other than from the Python standard libs. Different story :)

Comment: Well, [`os.symlink`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/os.html#os.symlink), [`os.lstat()`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/os.html#os.lstat) that doesn't follow links, and [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/os.html#os.walk) all exist since at least Python 2.6. If your requirements are stdlib only, they should work (although not in the prettiest way). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @AndrewF, I have just read the officail docs and did not pic up that weird order. Should be called `symlink_from`. This is a foot gun. In linux `cp`/`ln` its always FROM A to B.